# Splitting a matrix row based

Tags: r, matrix, split, divide

I have a question with dividing matrixes.

I have data of 100 rows and 1024 columns. I want to split that matrix into 2 sub matrices such that 8 rows to matrix 1 and 2 rows to matrix 2

first matrix will be formed

```
r1
r2
r3
r4
r5
r6
r7
r8
r11
r12
r13
...
...
```

and the second matrix will be formed with

```
r9
r10
r19
r20
...
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a logical index with `rep` and then use that to `split` the sequence of rows of `matrix`, subset the `matrix` based on the index vector in the `list`

```
out <-lapply(split(seq_len(nrow(m1)), rep(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(8, 2)), 
            length.out = nrow(m1))), function(i) m1[i, ] )
```

---

Also, as @user20650 mentioned in the comments, `?split.data.frame` can be used on matrices as well (based on documentation)

> The data frame method can also be used to split a matrix into a list of matrices, and the replacement form likewise, provided they are invoked explicitly.

```
out1 <- split.data.frame(m1, rep(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(8, 2)), 
          length.out = nrow(m1)))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(rnorm(100 * 1024), nrow = 100, ncol = 1024)
```

Comment: @user20650  That is nice, I was thinking about `split`.default` and then thought I have to convert the matrix to data.frame to do this

Comment: it works and much faster than my "for" loop, but I have one last question; is there a way to form "out" matrix without a header?

Comment: @Erdem Did you meant the column names of each matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Probabaly the easiest way is to define the indices and then to subset the matrix:

```
idx10 <- 1:10*10 # contains 10, 20, 30, ..., 100
idx9 <- idx10 - 1 #contain 9, 19, 29, ..., 99

idx <- c(idx9, idx10)

a <- matrix(rnorm(200), nrow = 100)

a_910 <- a[idx,]
a_rest <- a[-idx]
```